# ArrayList's add(index, object) method throw OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, arraylist, out-of-memory

Error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at mcs.controllers.StatsController$PatenteController.loadPatentes(StatsController.java:116) ~[?:?]
```

My Code:

```
private List<Patente> patentes = new ArrayList<>();

int exp = 301; 
for(int i=0; i<patentes.size(); i++) {
 if(exp<patentes.get(i).getRequiredEXP()) {
    patentes.add(i, pat); //Line 116 (where the error occurs)
  } else {
    x=i+1;
 }
}
```

The server remains stationary for a while, and soon after this error happens.

Comment: this code would create an infinitely large list, as soon as the condition `exp<patentes.get(i).getRequiredEXP()` is fulfilled, due to the fact that `patentes.add(i , pat)` will push the element that was previously at position `i` to position `i + 1`, and thus the condition will be fulfilled in the next step of the loop again. Since java only has limited memory, the `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown.

Comment: @Paul But only added 5 elements during the loop. How i fix it?

Comment: You are using `patentes.size()` in the loop condition and the size is growing each time you add a new element -> infinite loop.

Comment: @MakilêlêMaki-Maki debug the code. I bet 5 elements won't do

Comment: @Paul Really are creating an infinite loop. How do I analyze all current elements of the list, without this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This code would create an infinitely large list, as soon as the condition `exp<patentes.get(i).getRequiredEXP()` is fulfilled, due to the fact that `patentes.add(i , pat)` will push the element that was previously at position `i` to position `i + 1`, and thus the condition will be fulfilled in the next step of the loop again. The loop runs until `i` reaches `patentes.size()`, which will be increased by 1, every time you add a new element. Thus you create an infinite loop adding elements to the list. Since java only has limited memory, the `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown.

Comment: OMG! Really are creating an infinite loop. How do I analyze all current elements of the list, without this happening?

Comment: Depends upon what you mean by "analyze". if you only want to **find** the elements in the list that match the condition, just iterate over the list and check the condition for each element.